# add items to a queue and process one by one using setInterval

Tags: reactjs, web

I'm attempting to have the ability to add items (one by one) to a queue, and process an item one at a time (say every N seconds). The below code seems to add the numbers to the queue, however, reading `nums` from the setInterval reads an empty array every time. What could be happening here?

[image: Demo]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [nums, setNums] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`Nums > `, nums);
      const nextNums = [...nums];
      const nextNum = nextNums.pop();
      setNums(nextNums);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(nums)}
      <div>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map((val) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => {
              setNums([...nums, val])
            }}>
              {val}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: did you try to put ```nums``` in ```useEffect``` array of dependencies ?

Comment: That worked, thanks. My thought process was, i should do this just once when the component mounted.